# Confused about char array

Tags: c++

i was trying to understand char array more
with the following code

```
int main() {
    char test[] = "hello";
    char here[4] = "ola";
    char bon[] = { 'w','o','r','d' };
    char word[4] = { 'z','f','f','z' };

    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    std::cout << here << std::endl;
    std::cout << bon << std::endl;
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output is

```
hello
ola
wordhello
zffzwordhello
```

why it gave me this output not

```
hello
ola
word
zffz
```

Comment: You are missing a `'\0'` character in the end here: `char bon[] = { 'w','o','r','d' };.`

Comment: And the same for "word".

Comment: If you pass a string to an output routine, the routine does not know how long that string is. Roughly said: it keeps on printing until it reaches the first `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that null-terminator character (`'\0'`) is implicitly added in first two statements, but not in the in the last two in which you explicitly set array elements. This leads to undefined behavior when you try to print out the arrays (this means that output can vary, or that application might crash, depending on the compiler). The `<<` operator needs the null-terminator so it knows when to stop printing. You need to add the null-terminator, like this:

```
char bon[] = { 'w','o','r','d','\0' };
char word[5] = { 'z','f','f','z','\0' };
```

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes I know, and as you can see I have already said that in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: I didn't mean to tell you. I simply forgot the proper adressation. I meant this for the OP. Sorry.